# PHP file_get_contents() returns "illegal: d - msg" for certain image paths

Tags: php, image, dom

I use PHP's file_get_contents() on image paths taken from  'src' attributes in order to pull images from external websites and save them onto my own server. This almost always works. For some reason when I pass the following link in as an argument:

```
$arg = "http://s1.reutersmedia.net/resources/r/?m=02&d=20131205&t=2&i=817503382"

file_get_contents($arg)
```

returns

```
illegal: d - msg.
```

Why is this and how can I successfully get this image onto my server?

Comment: Did you examine the contents returned? Maybe it is not serving the image data back to you but rather an error message forbidding you from scraping it, rate limiting you, firewalling you, etc.

Comment: It doesn't here. But I'd contact the owner of that server.

Comment: (incidentally, I can call that URL as posted via `file_get_contents()` and store it to a .png file just fine...

Comment: It works for me, so nothing wrong with the url or file_get_contents.

Comment: Slightly tangential to this topic, but are you sure that you have the **RIGHTS** to copy and store images from external website inside your own server?

Comment: Works fine for me. Is it possible that you've simply been banned?

Comment: try using curl instead so you can view the response code

Comment: Just to expand a bit on what @MichaelBerkowski said. `file_get_contents()` returns false on failure, so what ever "message" you are getting is generated by the remote server.

Comment: @STT LCU that's a good question. Does pinterest have the right to pull images as they do? My system works in a similar way.

Comment: I use `curl_exec()` for this to stream the image to a file. The file ends up containing the exact text you mention, instead of the image.